# Best portal to integrate with OpenERP

Tags: odoo, portal

I am having openERP installed on my server now I need some functionality of portal website like forums, blogs and social networking which are not available in OpenERP.

Can anyone suggest me best portal which can easily integrate with OpenERP with less effort.

Or if OpenERP supports these modules Where can I found it or how can I develop it?

Answer (score 6):

OpenERP v7 has [out-of-the-box social features](http://v6.openerp.com/node/1269#h.9djynfxpycrp):

- *Forums*: The OpenChatter widget provides a comment wall on business documents, that can act as a discussion forum.
- *Networking*: Users can "follow" (subscribe the feed for new messages on the wall) and "star"/"like" (add to favourites / to-do list).
- *Blogging*: you could just use the OpenChatter on the Employee's or User document. Or for something more collaborative, there is a <s>"Wiki"</s> "Document Pages" feature available.

[image: Start page from OpenERP 7]

So my suggestion to you is to have a look to the v7.
You can:

- try it at the [Runbot site](http://runbot.openerp.com/): find a `trunk` branch with a green light and click on the `Connect` button. Username and password is `admin`.
- [download](http://nightly.openerp.com/trunk/nightly/) and install it locally.

For serious play, I advise using a Ubuntu Server box for host, even if you need to setup a VM for that. The [Opensourcerer's installation guide](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2011/04/19/how-to-install-openerp-6-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-server-part-1/) is a must read, but I also recommend [Sisalp's `install_xoe` script](http://openerpmanagementsystem.blogspot.pt/2012/02/openerp-easy-installation-using-sisalps.html): it's installed with 3 lines, and then can fully automate a server instance with one line.

To further develop specific functionalities, there's a learning curve to follow, rather steep at first. The best way to start is to follow the [v6.1 docs](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/index.html). There is some [documentation for v7](https://openerp-server.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but it's rather incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

In OPENERP 7.0 there is a module which called social networking which will be installed by default. I think this will be helpful for you.